# npm package for BLE in react native

Tags: react-native, npm-package, react-native-ble-plx

Is there any trustable BLE NPM package for react native can be used instead of react-native-ble-plx.

Reason for not choosing react-native-ble-plx: because the data send through the BLE with react-native-ble-plx by default must base64 format but I need to write and read in string format. If use react-native-ble-plx, it will return :

> BleError: Cannot write to characteristic 000ffxxx....xxxx with invalid data format: xx,xxxx

Are there any recommendations for other NPM packages?

I tried to use react-native-ble-plx to write string data through BLE but return error on invalid data format.

I'm expecting to use new NPM package because there is no way to change the data format to base64 in my project

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/181.